# Sobel edge detector in R?

Tags: r, image-processing, edge-detection, sobel

I am working on an R assignment about Sobel edge-detection. Unfortunately the video tutorial I was following uses R for every other task, but switches to python for image processing - I am guessing he did not find any useful R package for image convolution type work (this tutorial is from last year). I have tried [EBImage](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) and [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) (this one seems new), but did not find much. This [magick vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) talks about`image_convolve('Sobel')`(about half way down the page) but only for vertical edges, not horizontal. Can someone suggest some good material that I can use? I am fairly new to image processing.

**Update:**

I have managed to get as far as detecting vertical and horizontal edges separately using magick package (code pasted below), but do not know how to combine them to generate a single image

```
library(magick)

# get image
img <- image_read("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")
print(image_info(img))

# define horizontal and vertical Sobel kernel
Shoriz <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1), nrow = 3)
Svert <- t(Shoriz)

# get horizontal and vertical edges
imgH <- image_convolve(img, Shoriz)
imgV <- image_convolve(img, Svert)

print(plot(as.raster(img)))     # view original image
print(plot(as.raster(imgH)))    # view horizontal edges
print(plot(as.raster(imgV)))    # view vertical edges
```

From the tutorial, next I need to combine`imgH`and`imgV`by computing the Euclidean distance between these edges, but`dist()`won't work with the image objects themselves. I need to get the data from these images, but do not know how. Something similar to`imageData()`in`EBImage`package would help, but cannot find it in`magick`.It has`image_data()`function, but its output looks complicated.

**Update(2):**

I have (hopefully) got what I wanted with`EBImage`package (code below). I'd still like to get it working with`magick`package, once I figure out how to get pixel data from edge images as described above, and also how to transform the final edge data back to image.

```
library(EBImage)

# get image
img <- readImage("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png")
print(img, short = T)

# define horizontal and vertical Sobel kernel
Shoriz <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1), nrow = 3)
Svert <- t(Shoriz)

# get horizontal and vertical edges
imgH <- filter2(img, Shoriz)
imgV <- filter2(img, Svert)

# combine edge pixel data to get overall edge data
hdata <- imageData(imgH)
vdata <- imageData(imgV)
edata <- sqrt(hdata^2 + vdata^2)

# transform edge data to image
imgE <- Image(edata, colormode = 2)
print(display(combine(img, imgH, imgV, imgE), method = "raster", all = T))
```

Thanks.